# AutoLayout With a Label, Textfield(embedded button), CustomObject View

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am attempting to create a layout that has is formatted like this. I have a navigation controller also. I also have a button overlayed in the corner of my textfield. I set up in storyboard equal height constraints between the background and the objects, but the height still is not adjusting on different screen sizes. What am I doing wrong? My background is also not shrinking to fit, so that is possibly why my heights are not shrinking, my background height is not adjusting so no proportional heights adjust.

Label 25% of screen
Textfield(embedded button) 50% of screen 
CustomObject View 25% of screen

Comment: Share your code here that you've tried

Comment: I have been using storyboard only. My constraints are equal heights between the three objects and my background and then using a multiplier of .25 or .5

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I am at school right now, so I cannot access my app. The problem is that none of the heights are adjusting. The height for my label, textfield and custom object are all the same for every screen size.

Comment: Also what screenshots of my storyboard would you like when I am at home?